# Change wallpaper at random time intervals?

Tags: 18.04, desktop-background, time

I was recently searching for wallpaper managers for Ubuntu 18.04. I remember coming across one that had the option of changing the wallpaper at random time intervals. Problem is, I cannot find what it was called. Does anyone here know of any? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with one specifically, but this is one of those things that a little programming can go a long way. A bash script to change the wallpaper and a cronjob to schedule it at different times (or to mimic "random").

Comment: Cinnamon DE has this feature http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2014/09/cinnamon-2-4-background-slideshows/

Comment: I'm using it myself you can set any interval when you want to change it also you can make it random.

Answer (score 0):

This website suggests 4 automatic wallpaper changer applications: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/4-wallpaper-changer-ubuntu-18-04/

Hopefully one of these will be of use to you. In fact, the first suggestion is a pre-installed program on Ubuntu 18.04, so if you are happy with that, you won't need to install any software at all!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Variety, the PPA has the latest version
https://launchpad.net/~peterlevi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

You could probably add to the time change variable and add a random multiplier (it's in python)